# AnyLogic_Parking_Simulation

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am simulating car parking in AnyLogic. I have created simple process of car parking using road traffic library blocks.

I want to show that 10 cars are already there in parking lot before generating cars by source block at the start of my simulation experiment. It is required to get realistic feeling in simulation. Link of my model is given below:

https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/fae9eddf-d22e-4d1b-b392-32b124ca2247?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL

Please help me if anybody know the solution.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate cars in parking spots using the car source in the beginning of the simulation:
[image: car source in parking lot]

then to generate 10 cars in that source you can use the following code in your model startup:

```
carSource.inject(10);
```

Comment: Here, I am providing link of my model.

Comment: Due to some problem, it is not possible to upload model. But it is showing "Route to the specified destination can't be found".

Comment: that problem can be anything... and it's not related to the question you are asking... so i can't help you there

Comment: Sir, You told that you can select 'in parking lot' option in 'carSource' block to get 10 cars already having parked in parking lots by code 'carSource.inject(10);' at startup box in main but it is showing error due to not getting road for cars which is generated by source while running simulation experiment.

Comment: what you are saying is false... the error is caused somewhere else and if you don't show your model, it's impossible to guess

Comment: Please try to help in detailed screenshots.